# Equivalence of condition on function

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, reference-request, lp-spaces

In a book I am studying it states that a condition on a function $g$ as follows:

Given the function $g: \Omega \times \mathbb{R} \mapsto \mathbb{R}$ is a Caratheodory function satisfying $$\sup_{|u| \leq s}|g(x,u)| \leq h_{s}(x)$$ 
for a.e. $x \in \Omega$, all $s > 0$ and some function $h_{s} \in L^{\frac{1}{1-\epsilon}}(\Omega)$, $0 < \epsilon < 1$.

Why can't this simply be written as:

Given a function $g: \Omega \times \mathbb{R} \mapsto \mathbb{R}$ is a Caratheodory function such that $$|g(x,u)| \leq h(x)$$ for some $h \in L^{\frac{1}{1-\epsilon}}(\Omega), 0 < \epsilon < 1$?

Thanks

Comment: The top condition uses a different function $h_s$ for each given $s>0$. The bottom condition attempts to substitute one $h$ for all of the above $h_s$. Is there a reason you think you should be able to do this?

Comment: @AlexG. Further in the text I am using it uses that $g \in L^{1}(\Omega)$. I'm trying to show that $g \in L^{1}(\Omega)$. I thought this might be a possible way to show this...